# Missing dependency when using enableStompBrokerRelay using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to create a spring 5 MVC project, where I would be connecting to RabbitMQ with STOMP over WebSocket.

When I configure the SocketConfig with enableStompBrokerRelay I get an exception while starting the app.

pom.xml

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class SocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic").setRelayHost("localhost").setRelayPort(61613).setSystemLogin("guest").setSystemPasscode("guest");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.panda.socketprogramming</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor.spring/reactor-spring-messaging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor.spring/reactor-spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-tcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.31.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor.ipc/reactor-netty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.ipc</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.15.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I get this exception when starting the app

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/netty/resources/LoopResources
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart (DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200 (DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start (DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans (DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh (DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:893)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext (FrameworkServlet.java:701)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext (FrameworkServlet.java:577)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean (FrameworkServlet.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init (HttpServletBean.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init (GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet (ServletHolder.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize (ServletHolder.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize (ServletHandler.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext (ServletContextHandler.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp (WebAppContext.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp (JettyWebAppContext.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart (JettyWebAppContext.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart (ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty (AbstractJettyMojo.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute (AbstractJettyMojo.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute (JettyRunMojo.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/netty/resources/LoopResources
```

What is the minimal configuration to do this?

When I use `config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");` instead of `config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic").setRelayHost("localhost").setRelayPort(61613).setSystemLogin("guest").setSystemPasscode("guest");` I'm able to bring the application up.

Answer (score 1):

Add dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

to pom as it contains the missing `LoopResources` class.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I still get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.config()Lio/netty/bootstrap/BootstrapConfig;`